# Laplace problem for a circle with different type of boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

Let us consider the Laplace problem $\Delta u=0$ with the unitary circle as domain.

The boundary conditions are:
  \begin{cases}
    u=1       & \quad \text{if } \rho=1 \text{ and } \theta\in[\pi/2-\alpha; \pi/2+\alpha]\\
u=-1 & \quad \text{if } \rho=1 \text{ and } \theta\in[3\pi/2-\alpha; 3\pi/2+\alpha]\\
    \nabla u\cdot \hat{\rho}=0  & \quad \text{if } \rho=1 \text{ and } \theta\in\{[0; \pi/2-\alpha]\cup[\pi/2+\alpha; 3\pi/2-\alpha]\cup[3\pi/2+\alpha; 2\pi]\}
  \end{cases}
where $\hat{\rho}$ is the unit radial versor.

I am interested in finding an analytical solution over the whole domain.

Comment: The problems is in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and for analytical solution I mean an explicit solution or a series solution.

Comment: Did you try using separation of variables of the polar Laplacian?

Comment: Yes, but I haven't obtain any useful result.